# divs get bunched up when zooming in

Tags: html, css

I have written a website that looks fine on a standard unzoomed screen. When I zoom in however, the divs get all bunched up and overlap eachother. Here's a snippet of my banner area:

```
    <div id="topBanner" class="topBanner"> <!-- This wraps up the banner area at the top -->
        <div  class="logoWrapper"> <!-- This helps keep the logo contained within it's area -->
            <img id="logo" class="logo" src="img/square_altBlue_logo.gif" alt="Mr C Logo">
        </div> <!-- end logo div -->
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="titlediv">
                <h1 class="mrc name">MrC</h1>
            </div> <!-- End Mr C area -->
            <div class="titlediv numbers">
                <h2 class="phone name">PH: 07 46 348 550</h2>
                <h2 class="phone name">PH: 0401 398 800</h2>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End namespace area -->
        <div class="ccs name">
                <h3>COMMERCIAL CLEANING SERVICE</h3>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End banner area -->
```

This is inside a another wrapper div which has these styles

```
.wrapper {
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    background-color: #2C4870;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

the CSS for the banner area is here:
.logoWrapper {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#logo   {
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.banner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.titlediv {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}

.name   {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

.mrc    {
    font-size: 130px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.phone  {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.numbers    {
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;
}

.ccs    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    right: 80px;
}
```

I've looked around the forums here but most posts seem to be about lower resolutions or browser resizing, and none of those methods have worked. I need to fix this for zooming.

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of what you want to design? In general i see some minor mistakes like margin multli-declarations. I think the problem is that you reuse some classes (titlediv) at the wrong place. You should probably make the left part float left and the right part float right, but since you defined titlediv for both everything is floating left

Comment: I can post the URL - Please remove if not allowed. http://mrccleaningservices.com/

Comment: So basically your problem is that the boxes are overlapping as soon as you zoom close enough? What is the wanted behaviour? Should the text resize? should it be aligned on top of each other?

Comment: I would like it to look the same. I'd prefer a scroll bar to pop up if it goes below the minimum width which is defined by min-width: 768px for the div wrapper; Then everything inside that can remain where it is.